# Regex Pattern to match between the characters

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to extract the info from the paragraph.

I want to get everything between the first (`State:`) and the (`<br>`).

Please see the link below.
http://regexr.com/4uphu

This is the case:

```
<b>Bank:</b> <a href="#">ABU DHABI COMMERCIAL BANK</a><br><br><b>Address:</b>
```

If possible I need to extract this `ABU DHABI COMMERCIAL BANK`.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a `State:` in the text you are extracting from. And in your regexr example that string doesn't occur after a `State:` string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to match the text between the anchor tags.

```
<a[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>
```

If you only want to match after "Bank:" then use the below:

```
<b>Bank:<\/b>\s<a[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>
```